# How register (call) jQuery function from asp.net usercontrol from codebehind file?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How register (call) jQuery function from asp.net usercontrol from codebehind file?

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel or is this on page load?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx), for example:

```
var script = "$(function() { $('#message').fadeIn(); });";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "keyHere", script, true);
```

This gets rendered to the page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { $('#message').fadeIn(); });
</script>
```

The script is just any JavaScript, nothing special about jQuery, just put in there whatever you would manually put in the page, since that's how it ends up.

Comment: @Bendar - Welcome! And welcome to SO! Be sure to accept answers, mingle with the natives and enjoy your stay :)